# Corda - transaction.fails() not working while running Test

Tags: corda

I am very new to Corda.
transaction.fails() not working while running Test

---- Code ---

```
@Override
public void verify(LedgerTransaction tx) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    Command command = tx.getCommand(0);
    private final TestIdentity alice = new TestIdentity(new CordaX500Name("Alice", "", "GB"));                       
    private final TestIdentity bob = new TestIdentity(new CordaX500Name("Bob", "", "GB"));                           
    private MockServices ledgerServices = new MockServices(new TestIdentity(new CordaX500Name("TestId", "", "GB"))); 
    private TokenState tokenState = new TokenState(alice.getParty(), bob.getParty(), 1);                             

    if (tx.getInputStates().size() != 0) {
        System.out.println(" -- Checking Input Size -- ");
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(" Transaction Must have No Inputs ");
    }
}
```

--- in Test Case  --

```
@Test                                                                    
public void tokenContractRequiresZeroInputsInTheTransaction() {                
    transaction(ledgerServices, tx -> {                                       
        //Has an input, will fail.                                            
        tx.input(TokenContract.ID, tokenState);                              
        tx.output(TokenContract.ID, tokenState);                             
        tx.command(alice.getPublicKey(), new TokenContract.Commands.Issue());
        tx.fails();                                                          
        return null;                                                         
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This test will pass, as expected.

The call to `tx.fails()` means that given the transaction as it currently stands, calling the `verify` method should throw an exception for at least one of the transaction's contracts. If it doesn't, `tx.fails()` will throw an exception, causing the test to fail.

In your case, calling the `verify` method of your `TokenContract` will throw an exception because the transaction has an input, causing the contract to throw an exception. `tx.fails()` will therefore *not* throw an exception, and your test will pass.

P.S. You shouldn't use test classes such as `TestIdentity` and `MockServices` directly inside `verify`.